# MVC - User Impersonation (View Site as User)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, cookies, impersonation

I would like to add a 'view site as another user' functionality to an asp.net MVC 4  website.
I have implemented this by setting authentication cookie to the required user to impersonate. I have also  set it so that the cookie expires after 5 mins in which case any further request made after this time would cause the impersonated user to be logged out.

`HttpCookie authCookie = FormsAuthentication.GetAuthCookie(userToImpersonate, true);`
Is there a way to switch back to the original logged in user like an 'admin' without having to log out ? It is pretty much the same  functionality that facebook has where you can view a page as another user but not necessarily logging in as that user.

I know there are a couple of ways to accomplish this as I have tried above, but is there a better or recommended way of achieving this?